# Aggregation by positive/negative values v.2

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've posted several topics and every query had some problems :( Changed table and examples for better understanding

I have a table called `PROD_COST` with 5 fields

`(ID,Duration,Cost,COST_NEXT,COST_CHANGE).`

I need extra field called "groups" for aggregation.

1. Duration = number of days the price is valid (1 day=1row).
2. Cost = product price in this day.
3. -Cost_next = lead(cost,1,0).
4. Cost_change = Cost_next - Cost.

example:

```
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|ID  |Duration | Cost | Cost_change | Groups|
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
|  1 | 1       | 10   | -1,5        | 1     |
|  2 | 1       | 8,5  | 3,7         | 2     |
|  3 | 1       | 12.2 | 0           | 2     |
|  4 | 1       | 12.2 | -2,2        | 3     |
|  5 | 1       | 10   |  0          | 3     |
|  6 | 1       | 10   | 3.2         | 4     |
|  7 | 1       | 13.2 | -2,7        | 5     |
|  8 | 1       | 10.5 | -1,5        | 5     |
|  9 | 1       | 9    |  0          | 5     |
| 10 | 1       | 9    |  0          | 5     | 
| 11 | 1       | 9    | -1          | 5     |
| 12 | 1       | 8    | 1.5         | 6     |
+----+---------+------+-------------+-------+
```

Now i need to group("Groups" field) by Cost_change. It can be positive,negative or 0 values.
Some kind guy advised me this query:

```
select id, COST_CHANGE, sum(GRP) over (order by id asc) +1
from
   (
    select    *, case when sign(COST_CHANGE) != sign(isnull(lag(COST_CHANGE) 
     over (order by id asc),COST_CHANGE)) and Cost_change!=0 then 1 else 0 end as GRP
    from PROD_COST
   ) X
```

But there is a problem: If there are 0 values between two positive or negative values than it groups it separately, for example:

```
 +-------------+--------+
 | Cost_change | Groups |
 +-------------+--------+
 | 9.262       |   5777 |
 | -9.262      |   5778 |
 | 9.262       |   5779 |
 | 0.000       |   5779 |
 | 9.608       |   5780 |
 | -11.231     |   5781 |
 | 10.000      |   5782 |
 +-------------+--------+
```

I need to have:

```
 +-------------+--------+
 | Cost_change | Groups |
 +-------------+--------+
 | 9.262       |   5777 |
 | -9.262      |   5778 |
 | 9.262       |   5779 |
 | 0.000       |   5779 |
 | 9.608       |   5779 | -- Here
 | -11.231     |   5780 |
 | 10.000      |   5781 |
 +-------------+--------+
```

In other words, if there's 0 values between two positive ot two negative values than they should be in one group, because Sequence: MINUS-0-0-MINUS - no rotation. But if i had MINUS-0-0-PLUS, than GROUPS should be 1-1-1-2, because positive valus is rotating with negative value.
Thank you for attention!

**I'm Using Sql Server 2012**

Comment: You should tag the question with the version of SQL Server you are using.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best approach is to remove the zeros, do the calculation, and then re-insert them. So:

```
with pcg as (
      select pc.*, min(id) over (partition by grp) as grpid
      from (select pc.*,
                   (row_number() over (order by id) -
                    row_number() over (partition by sign(cost_change)
                                       order by id
                   ) as grp 
            from prod_cost pc
            where cost_change <> 0
           ) pc
     )
select pc.*, max(groups) over (order by id)
from prod_cost pc left join
      (select pcg.*, dense_rank() over (order by grpid) as groups
       from pcg
     ) pc
     on pc.id = pcg.id;
```

The CTE assigns a group identifier based on the lowest id in the group, where the groups are bounded by actual sign changes.  The subquery turns this into a number.  The outer query then accumulates the maximum value, to give a value to the `0` records.

Comment: @RussianBear7 . . . It doesn't take an argument.  I'm not sure why I put one in.

Comment: the other error on the last row, could you correct pls?